# JavaFX: Add MapView to VBox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, jxmapviewer, jxmaps

I want to add a MapView from JXMaps to the VBox in JavaFX, i tried to add the MapView to the border panel and then added to the VBox, but i can´t find any solution to this, i hope you can help me, this is my code:

```
 public class ControlerMap
 {
     @FXML private BorderPane borderPanel;
     @FXML private Button butom;
     @FXML VBox cosa;

     @FXML public void initialize() 
     {
         MapView sample = new MapView();
         sample.setMaxHeight(394.0);
         sample.setPrefWidth(704.0);
         sample.setVisible(true);
         borderPanel = new BorderPane(sample);
         borderPanel.setVisible(true);
         borderPanel.setLayoutX(76.0);
         borderPanel.setLayoutY(134.0);
         borderPanel.setPrefHeight(200.0);
         borderPanel.setPrefWidth(467.0);
         cosa.getChildren().add(borderPanel);
     }
}
```

And here is my code from the .FXML file:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="496.0" prefWidth="757.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="prueba.web.googleMap.ControlerMap">
<children>
      <Button fx:id="butom" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="14.0" 
     mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
     <VBox fx:id="cosa" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="394.0" 
      prefWidth="704.0">
      <children>
         <BorderPane fx:id="borderPanel" prefHeight="400.0" 
             prefWidth="704.0" />
      </children>
     </VBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You made the pref height of your `VBox` 394, which is smaller even than the first border pane you added to it in the FXML file. So when you add the second border pane in the controller, it will go below the existing border pane, and will likely not be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you created empty MapView.

```
MapView sample = new MapView();
```

Maps will be actually drawn only after initialization of its properties (at least zoom and center). You have to set it in following way:

```
sample.setOnMapReadyHandler(new MapReadyHandler() {
       @Override
       public void onMapReady(MapStatus status) {
          if (status == MapStatus.MAP_STATUS_OK) {
              final Map map = mapView.getMap();
              map.setCenter(new LatLng(35.91466, 10.312499));
              map.setZoom(2.0);
          }
       }
});
```